# Inserting a data field into a vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am in the process of building a vue.js site that serves as an internal code repository for my office. My goal is to create a number of pages that will preview how a block of code will look, and beneath it have a textarea with the code needed to copy/paste it.

Ideally, I'd like to use only one data field containing the HTML block that I can place it in my site twice; once outside the textarea to preview how it looks, and once within the textarea for the user to copy

I've tried placing either the `v-html` or the `<copycode></copycode>` component tag within a hardcoded `<textarea>` in the HTML but any content within it will get rendered before vue has a chance to swap out the content like the items shown in the example.

Within the demo provided below, I have a vue component separated intro three concatenated strings. Is there a way to replace the middle string `(code goes here)` with the data field `sampleCode` in the new vue below it?

```js
Vue.component('copycode', {
  template: '<textarea id="codeblock01">' + '(code goes here)' + '</textarea>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sampleCode: 
    `<table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <p>Content Block Demo</p>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>`,
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial', 'helvetica', sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <!--renders the code I wish to demo from vue data-->
  <span v-html="sampleCode"></span>
  
  <!--renders the textarea that will allow users to easily copy the code-->
  <copycode></copycode>

</div>
```

data field `sampleCode` in the new vue below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the component to know about a data item, you need to [pass the item as a prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props). Then you can just use the curly braces to interpolate it into your textarea as in the example below.

If you want changes in the textarea to be reflected in the parent, you'll need to [emit and handle input events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events). The example below doesn't do that.

```js
Vue.component('copycode', {
  template: '<textarea id="codeblock01">{{value}}</textarea>',
  props: ['value']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sampleCode: 
    `<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Content Block Demo</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>`,
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial', 'helvetica', sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <!--renders the code I wish to demo from vue data-->
  <span v-html="sampleCode"></span>
  
  <!--renders the textarea that will allow users to easily copy the code-->
  <copycode :value="sampleCode"></copycode>

</div>
```